# How to fix ImproperlyConfigured : QuerySet class does not inherit from TranslatableQuerySet

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

My project has ImproperlyConfigured  error. Help me please.

Error body :

```
Internal Server Error: /en/admin/posts/post/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\news-Jjvbi-2o\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\news-Jjvbi-2o\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\news-Jjvbi-2o\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 614, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\news-Jjvbi-2o\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\news-Jjvbi-2o\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\news-Jjvbi-2o\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 233, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\news-Jjvbi-2o\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\news-Jjvbi-2o\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\news-Jjvbi-2o\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1693, in changelist_view
    cl = self.get_changelist_instance(request)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\news-Jjvbi-2o\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 735, in get_changelist_instance
    return ChangeList(
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\news-Jjvbi-2o\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py", line 57, in __init__
    self.root_queryset = model_admin.get_queryset(request)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\news-Jjvbi-2o\lib\site-packages\parler\admin.py", line 279, in get_queryset
    qs = super().get_queryset(request)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\news-Jjvbi-2o\lib\site-packages\parler\admin.py", line 150, in get_queryset
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: QuerySet class does not inherit from TranslatableQuerySet
[26/Jan/2022 11:06:32] "GET /en/admin/posts/post/ HTTP/1.1" 500 108753
```

my settings.py :

```
"""
Django settings for config project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _ 

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # tashqi app
    'rest_framework',
    "corsheaders",
    'rosetta',
    'taggit',
    'hitcount',
    'parler',
    
    # ichki app
    'posts',
    
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':[
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'
    ]
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://localhost:8000",
    # 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
    # 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates'))],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'libraries' : {
                'staticfiles': 'django.templatetags.static', 
            }
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/




LANGUAGES = (
('uz', _('Uzbek')),
('ru', _('Russian')),
('en', _('English')),
('tr', _('Turkish')),
)

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tashkent'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    BASE_DIR, 'locale/',
)


PARLER_LANGUAGES = {
None: (
{'code': 'uz'},
{'code': 'ru'},
{'code': 'en'},
{'code': 'tr'},
),
'default': {
'fallback': 'en',
'hide_untranslated': False,
}
}


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

# STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# STATIC_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'static/'
# # STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/'
# # STATICFILES_DIRS = (
# #     #This lets Django collectstatic store our bundles
# #     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'), 
# #     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'resources'), 
# # )
# STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('static')),) # new
STATIC_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('staticfiles')) # new
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'



# MEDIA
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

my models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from hitcount.models import HitCountMixin, HitCount
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation
from django.urls import reverse
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
from django.utils.html import mark_safe
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from parler.models import TranslatableModel, TranslatedFields



# Create your models here.

STATUS_CHOICES = ( 
        ('draft', 'Draft'), 
        ('published', 'Published'), 
    )

class PublishedManager(models.Manager): 
    def get_queryset(self): 
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')


class Post(TranslatableModel):
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        title = models.CharField(_('title'),max_length=200,  db_index=True),
        slug = models.SlugField(_('slug'), max_length=250, unique=True,  db_index=True),
        body = models.TextField(_("body"), db_index=True),  
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="post_images/%Y/%m/%d/")
    # publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) 
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) 
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft') 
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager. 
    published = PublishedManager() # Our custom manager.
    tags = TaggableManager() # Tag maneger

    
    # class Meta: 
    #     ordering = ('-publish',) 

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail',
                       args=[self.created.year,
                             self.created.month,
                             self.created.day,
                             self.slug])

    def avatar_tag(self):
        return mark_safe('<img src="/media/%s" width="50" height="50" />' % (self.image))
    
    avatar_tag.short_description = 'Rasmi'
```

my admin.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post, Card, Contact
from django.utils.html import mark_safe
from parler.admin import TranslatableAdmin
# Register your models here.

@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(TranslatableAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'author', 'created','status',"avatar_tag")
    list_filter = ('status', 'created',  'author')
    search_fields = ('title', 'body')
    raw_id_fields = ('author',)
    date_hierarchy = 'created'
    ordering = ('status', 'created')
    readonly_fields = ('avatar_tag',)

    def get_prepopulated_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        return {'slug': ('title',)}

    def avatar_tag(self, obj):
        return obj.avatar_tag

    avatar_tag.short_description = 'Rasmi'
 my views.py :


class ListPost(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.order_by('-created').all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

py serializer.py :

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Post, Card

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            'id', 
            'title', 
            'slug',
            'author',
            'image',
            'body',
            'publish',
            'status',
        )
```

py urls.py(in app):

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ListPost, DetailPost, ListCard, DetailCard
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

urlpatterns = [
    path(_('<int:pk>/'), DetailPost.as_view()),
    path(_(''), ListPost.as_view()),
    path(_('<int:pk>/card/'), DetailCard.as_view()),
]
```

my urls.py(main) :

""

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from posts.views import ContactView

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns (
    path(_('admin/'), admin.site.urls),
    path('rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls')),
    path(_('posts/'), include('posts.urls'), name='posts'),
    path(_('hitcount/'), include(('hitcount.urls', 'hitcount'), namespace='hitcount')),
    path('contact/', ContactView, name='contact')
 )
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I have 2 model. card and post . Card work but Post don't work.
I new in django because I don't find solve this problem before 2 days.

PLEASE GIVE ME SOLVE

Comment: What version of django-parler are you using if  1.5.1 and Django 1.8.14., i think you might need to  upgrade to django-parler==1.6.5 and Django==1.8.15.

Comment: Sometimes you just need to upgrade to latest vision of django-parler . i think it should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for ideas . but I have last version of parler :)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please add the error you are seeing and any useful logs

Comment: ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: QuerySet class does not inherit from TranslatableQuerySet

Comment: Same problem here

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I'm not sure what is the reason behind this, but I made a test with a small version of the project and if you delete the fields objects and published in the Post model it works. Probably there is a more technical solution, but for now I will try fixing this removing the model manager.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you just defined a custom queryset in
`objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.`

to solve this import `TranslatableQuerySet`

```
from parler.managers import TranslatableQuerySet
```

and make it like

```
objects = CustomQuerySet.as_manager()
```

and

```
class CustomQuerySet(TranslatableQuerySet):
  # Your custom queryset methods
  pass
```